# imagejpeg not working when used in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, jpeg

Good day. Why is that when I try to run my code on an external page, it works perfectly. But when I used wordpress to add it on my page, it gives me strange errors. Why is that and how do I fix that?

code:

```css
<?php
// (A) OPEN IMAGE
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550684376-efcbd6e3f031?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80');

// (B) WRITE TEXT
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$txt = "sad";
$font = realpath('arial.ttf');
//(IMAGE, FONT SIZE, TILT ANGLE, X, Y, COLOR, FONT, TEXT)
imagettftext($img, 12, 0, 253, 234, $white, $font, $txt);

// (C) OUTPUT IMAGE
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($img);

// OR SAVE TO A FILE
// THE LAST PARAMETER IS THE QUALITY FROM 0 to 100
imagejpeg($img, "test.jpg", 100);
?>
```

Here's the result I got when trying it on my wordpress page:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay5s7.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are running this in a shortcode and change the header of the output, that you already created, namely the page. It depends on what you want to do, if you want to display the image in the site:

```
 ob_start();
 imagejpeg( $img, NULL, 100 );
 imagedestroy( $img );
 $i = ob_get_clean();

 echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $i )."'>";
```